# How to mark array value types in PHP (Java)Doc?

Tags: php, class, arrays, javadoc, phpdoc

It might be a bit difficult to explain, so I'll give some example code. Note that I'm using NetBeans IDE (latest).

```
class Dummy {
    public function say(){ }
}
/**
 * Builds dummy class and returns it.
 * @return Dummy The dummy class.
 */
function say_something(){
  return new Dummy();
}
$s=say_something();
```

While developing in netbeans I can invoke auto-complete by hitting ctrl+space after typing "$s->".
In the the hint window that follows, there is the item "say()". This is because the javadoc says say_something returns a Dummy and NetBeans parsed Dummy class to know that it has a method called "say()".

So far so good.

My problem is with arrays. Example code follows:

```
/**
 * Builds array of 2 dummy classes and returns it.
 * @return Array The dummy class. (*)
 */
function say_something2(){
  return array(new Dummy(),new Dummy());
}
$s=say_something2();
```

If I try the auto-complete thing again but with "$s[0]->" instead, I don't get the methods fro Dummy class. This is because in the JavaDoc I only said that it is an array, *but not the values' type*.

So the question would be, is there any JavaDoc syntax, cheat, whatever which allows me to tell JavaDoc what type of variables to expect in an array?

Comment: As far as i know it is not possible if only IDE does not support this kind of feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. See the documentation [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/).